# Configure syslog.conf file

Tags: linux, logs, iptables, syslog

How can I configure `/etc/syslog.conf` file in order to save log information about `iptables` in a specific file.

I want to save these information separately, so I can extract what I want easily and rapidly.

Comment: Which logs, do you mean the logs configured with `iptables -j LOG`? I don't think you can do that with a basic syslog. Is installing rsyslog an option?